# Need to know logic behind few regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a code as

```
$wrk = OC192-1-1-1;

@temp = split (/-/, $wrk);

 if ($temp1[3] =~ /101 || 102 /)
{
    print "yes";
} else {
    print "no";
}
```

Output :

```
yes
```

Need to know why this is printing yes. I know for regular expression `|` is supported for OR operator. But need to know why `||` is giving as "yes" as output

Comment: You do know that `$temp1[3]` refers to another array called `@temp1`, and not the one you assign to here, `@temp`, right? You should always use `use strict; use warnings;`, it will catch errors like that.

Comment: @TLP : These are some silly mistakes that i have done while typing. It was a small part of code. So instead of copying from my editor, I typed the code and got few typo erros.

Comment: Yes, and that is why you should always copy/paste the code. If you need to remove parts of it, see that the code still compiles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because `||` will make regex match succeed by matching with nothing all the time.

So it is essentially matching `$temp1[3]` (which doesn't exist) with **anyone of the following**

- `"101 "`
- `""`
- `" 102 "`

I added double quotes just for explanation.

Comment: one query : why it is considering || as empty string

Comment: Because there is nothing between `|` and `|`. You need to use only one `|` for OR clause in regex and when you use `||` that means there is empty string between 2 pipes.

Comment: If you meant to include a literal pipe character on 2nd string then you need to escape it like `/101 |\| 102 /`

Comment: @Nitesh: It is quite amusing. Why did you change the acceptance decision twice? If you get multiple correct answers then as an unwritten SO protocol you select the answer that is correct and was posted first. OR else did you have any problems with my explanations?

Comment: Hey anubhava . Actually both answers are correct. I wish to accept both but SO allows to select only one.

Comment: @Nitesh: Both of them are correct and as a standard practice you should accept the correct and first answer. Other answer is also correct but it was posted 3 minutes after my answer and pretty much had the same content. (Honestly I would have deleted mine if I was few minutes late with same answer body, like Kent did it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20214137/548225)

Answer (score 7):

`/101 || 102 /` regex tries to match `'101 '`, or `''` (empty string), or `' 102 '`.

Since empty string can always be matched, it always returns true in your condition.

Comment: one query : why it is considering `||` as empty string

Comment: @Nitesh empty string is between pipes => `match this|or this|or this`

Comment: Still confused. I agree that empty string is between pipes. But about pipes itself. Why it is not taking pipe as character. U mean to say || is equivalent to "" (double quotes)

Comment: @Nitesh metacharacters like `|` should be escaped in order to be matched, eg. `\|` will match literal `|` char.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the regex-relevant answer from @anubhava, note that: `OC192-1-1-1` is same as `0-1-1-1`, which is just `"-3"`, therefore `@temp` evaluates to `( "", "3" )`

And of course there's no such thing as `$temp1`

Comment: How OC192-1-1-1 is same as 0-1-1-1 . Didn't get what you have answered. Can you explain further because it sounds interesting

Comment: @Nitesh This answer relies on the fact that you have failed to quote your string in your question, which will cause it to be evaluated as code instead. If you have `use warnings` on, it would issue a warning `Argument "OC192" isn't numeric in subtraction (-)`, and produce the number `-3` -- because it will evaluate to 4 subtractions. If you then split that number you will get `""` and `"3"`. So in a sense, it is correct. But of course, you were just being careless when you typed in your code, and that string is supposed to be quoted.